# Valor de entrada igual ao ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá, eu tenho uma table no postgres que possui uma coluna chamada link, serve para conectar dados com a mesma origem de diversas tabelas. Esta link é igual ao ID da tabela em questão 'tasks'. Como eu faço para que na hora que for entrar os dados, o valor de link entrar igual ao ID auto_increments (chave primária)?

Comment: Acredito que neste post tem sua resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id

Comment: Você pode utilizar em um bloco a cláusula RETURNING link do primeiro INSERT e utilizar este valor retornado nos demais INSERTs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html . Outra possibilidade é usar a função currval(sequencia) para obter o valor retornado pelo último nextval desta sequencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que seu modelo de dados seja algo como:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id_cliente;
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id_venda;

CREATE TABLE tb_cliente
(
  id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('seq_id_cliente') PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tb_venda
(
  id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('seq_id_venda') PRIMARY KEY,
  id_cliente BIGINT REFERENCES tb_cliente(id),
  produto TEXT,
  valor NUMERIC(9,2),
  datahora TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now()
);
```

Você pode usar a função `currval()` para recuperar o identificador de chave primária da tabela pai para gravá-lo como o identificador de chave estrangeira nas tabelas filhas, veja só:

```
-- CADASTRANDO CLIENTE (TABELA PAI)
INSERT INTO tb_cliente (nome) VALUES ('FULANO DE TAL');

-- CADASTRANDO VENDAS DO CLIENTE (TABELAS FILHAS)
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'LAPIS', 1.50);
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'CANETA', 3.35 );
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'CADERNO', 7.25);
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'BORRACHA', 0.50);

-- CADASTRANDO CLIENTE (TABELA PAI)
INSERT INTO tb_cliente (nome) VALUES ('BELTRANO DA SILVA');

-- CADASTRANDO VENDAS DO CLIENTE (TABELAS FILHAS)
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'APONTADOR', 3.30);
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'LAPISEIRA', 3.35);
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'REGUA', 7.25);
INSERT INTO tb_venda (id_cliente, produto, valor) VALUES (currval('seq_id_cliente'), 'GIZ DE CERA', 0.50);
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT
  v.id AS id_venda,
  v.id_cliente AS id_cliente,
  c.nome AS nome_cliente,
  v.produto AS nome_produto,
  v.valor AS valor_venda,
  v.datahora AS datahora_venda
FROM
  tb_venda AS v
JOIN
  tb_cliente AS c ON (v.id_cliente = c.id)
ORDER BY
  id_cliente,
  id_venda;
```

Saída:

```
| id_venda | id_cliente |      nome_cliente | nome_produto | valor_venda |              datahora_venda |
|----------|------------|-------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------------------------|
|        1 |          1 |     FULANO DE TAL |        LAPIS |         1.5 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        2 |          1 |     FULANO DE TAL |       CANETA |        3.35 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        3 |          1 |     FULANO DE TAL |      CADERNO |        7.25 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        4 |          1 |     FULANO DE TAL |     BORRACHA |         0.5 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        5 |          2 | BELTRANO DA SILVA |    APONTADOR |         3.3 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        6 |          2 | BELTRANO DA SILVA |    LAPISEIRA |        3.35 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        7 |          2 | BELTRANO DA SILVA |        REGUA |        7.25 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
|        8 |          2 | BELTRANO DA SILVA |  GIZ DE CERA |         0.5 | 2020-06-03T21:14:23.033329Z |
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/730c03/2)

Answer (score 1):

Para quem vem do MYSql o auto_increment No PostgreSQL o funcionamento é um pouco diferente, pois ele utiliza sequences (sequências) para controlar o "auto increment".

O recurso auto increment do PostgreSQL não é apenas uma opção na coluna e sim uma série de fatores que juntos determinam o efeito de somar um (ou n à sua chave primária), sendo eles:
Sequence (sequência) ? Um recurso do PostgreSQL utilizado para gerar números sequenciais
Nextval ? É uma função do PostgreSQL utilizada para obter o próximo valor de uma sequence.
Default value (valor padrão) ? Um recurso disponibilizado em uma coluna para determinar um valor padrão que o campo assumirá caso nada seja informado no comando de insert.

Isso tudo junto se resume à criação de um campo tipo Serial. Exemplo:
ALTER TABLE exemplo ADD COLUMN id Serial;

Ou então:
CREATE TABLE exemplo (
  id serial NOT NULL
)

Nesse caso, a coluna id será inserida e utilizará os 3 recursos acima e podemos observar a mensagem de retorno:
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE will create implicit sequence "exemplo_id_seq" for serial column "exemplo.id"
Consulta executada com sucesso sem resultados em 396 ms.
fonte de conhecimento: https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/postgresql/como_criar_um_campo_auto-increment_no_postgresql